# Count checkboxes within element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, checkbox

I'm trying to find a way to count all checked checkboxes *within* a parent element using jQuery. Sofar I haven't found a decent (and fast) solution.

To illustrate the situation: I've got an ul-list with one 'check-all' checkbox, and one checkbox per child list-item. When there are no checked list-items, I want the check-all checkbox to be unchecked. Therefore I assume I've to count all the checked list-items each time one of them is changed.

```
[...]
<li><input type="checkbox" class="checkall" />
<ul>
<li><input type="checkbox" id="ch1" class="list" /></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" id="ch2" class="list" /></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" id="ch3" class="list" /></li>
</ul>
</li>
[...]
```

As you can see I'm working with a nested ul-list, for the record.
Sofar I've got the following jQuery code, which serves for selecting the parent list-item, as I've only got to count the checkboxes within that 'group'.

```
// $(this).val() is neccesary for my code to know which checkbox has been affected
var parentnode = $('input#' + $(this).val()).parent().parent().parent();
alert(parentnode.children('input.list:checked').length);
```

I know it won't work using the children selector (that's for looping, right?), but I can't find a way to count the checked checkboxes length from the 'parentnode' element.. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) only processes the direct children of your element, you can use [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) instead to process all descendants matching the selector:

```
alert(parentnode.find('input.list:checked').length);
```